# CodeinGame Power of Thor level 2 wont work

Tags: c#, if-statement, logic

I was solving a problem in CodeinGame where i have to take Thor to the light lightx & lightY is the light position & thorx & thory is the position of thor.& initiaTX , initiaTX are starting thor position but it fails some test cases on the site for eg : 
if initial pos is (5,4) it passes [Log](http://pastebin.com/V8kFXxpC)
but if initial pos is (31,17) it fails [Log](http://pastebin.com/f60waLDf)

My code

```
        string[] inputs = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    int lightX = int.Parse(inputs[0]); // the X position of the light of power
    int lightY = int.Parse(inputs[1]); // the Y position of the light of power
    int initialTX = int.Parse(inputs[2]); // Thor's starting X position
    int initialTY = int.Parse(inputs[3]); // Thor's starting Y position

    // game loop

    int thorx=initialTX;
    int thory=initialTY;

    string directionX, directionY;

    while (true)
    {
        int remainingTurns = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // The remaining amount of turns Thor can move. Do not remove this line.

        // Write an action using Console.WriteLine()
        // To debug: Console.Error.WriteLine("Debug messages...");

        if (thorx>lightX)
        {
            directionX="W";
            thorx=-1;
            Console.WriteLine("W");
        }
        else if (thorx<lightX)
        {
            directionX="E";
            thorx=+1;
            Console.WriteLine("E");
        }
        else
        {
            if (thory>lightY)
            {
                directionY="N";    
                thory=-1;
                Console.WriteLine("N");
            }
            else if (thory<lightY)
            {
                directionY="S";
                thorx=+1;
                Console.WriteLine("S");
            }
        }
```

[CodeinGame Link](http://www.codingame.com) it's the 2nd problem Power of Thor

Comment: Fine, do you have a question?

Comment: @Steve edited the question

Comment: Check your Thor's going south code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of incrementing or decrementing the position variables you are resetting them to +/-1.  Here:

```
    if (thorx>lightX)
    {
        directionX="W";
        thorx=-1;
        Console.WriteLine("W");
    }
```

That should be:

```
    if (thorx>lightX)
    {
        directionX="W";
        thorx -= 1;
        Console.WriteLine("W");
    }
```

Or better, since you have absolutely no use for those `directionX` and `directionY` values:

```
    if (thorx>lightX)
    {
        thorx -= 1;
        Console.WriteLine("W");
    }
```

Next problem (as `vernerik` pointed out) is that you were adjusting the `thorx` when moving south.  South should increment `thory`.

And finally, this code moves west/east until vertically aligned with the target, then moves north/south, which is inefficient.  It will pass the first three tests but fail the fourth one - Optimal angle.  To pass that test you have to use the diagonal moves as well: NW, NE, SW, SE.